# React router navigate not working, but route does work manually

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This problem is occurring with React 18 built with Vite.  I am trying to trigger navigation back to the "/home" route when a form submission completes successfully.  I'm using react-router 6 (see package.json below).

Problem:
Calling navigate("/home") within a functional component changes the browser's address bar, but the app does not navigate.  It just remains on the form page even though the address bar has updated correctly.

Strangely, if I highlight the address bar and hit ENTER, it goes to the home page as expected.  So the route does work, but navigate("/home" does not.

**UPDATE** - As requested, I am rewriting this post, attempting to include a minimal reproduceable example.  This is extremely challenging in this case because this issue spans multiple components in the parent/child hierarchy of the app.  I am doing my best and trying to omit code that's not related to the problem.

**UPDATE 2** - Through trial and error I have gotten navigate("/home") to work in some cases, and I have identified the one thing that ultimately determines whether navigate("/home") works or not.  The submit handler sets state in RootLayout.tsx (parent component).  My understanding is that when state changes in a parent, all the children are re-rendered.  The pattern I've noticed is this:

- When state changes on the parent layout component during the form submission process, navigate("/home") doesn't work.  The address bar changes but the page remains unchanged.
- If I comment out the setting of state during the form submission process, navigate("/home") works normally.

**Question:** is it possible that navigate("/home") is being interrupted by the parent state change, and EditForm.tsx is getting re-rendered instead of navigating to /home?

**Ideas:** Assuming I'm on the right track with the above question, should I...

- Make the 'jobs' state a ref instead?  This seems like the wrong use case for ref, but it would prevent the state change in the RootLayout component and possible allow navigate() to work normally in the child.
- Add some arbitrary delay before setting 'job' state, allowing navigate() to complete first?  I hate this idea.

**App.tsx**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import RootLayout from './components/RootLayout';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage';
import ManageFeeds from './components/ManageFeeds';
import EditFeed from './components/EditFeed';
import { UserFeed } from './models';
import { AppService, ServiceResult } from './services/AppService';

function App(props: any) {
    const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
    
    const [jobs, setJobs] = useState<Job[]>([]);
    const [userFeeds, setUserFeeds] = useState<UserFeed[]>();
    const [activeUserFeed, setActiveUserFeed] = useState<UserFeed>();
    const appService = new AppService(instance, accounts[0], [props.msalConfig.scopes]);

    const getAccessToken = async () => {
        const msalResponse = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({
            scopes: [props.msalConfig.scopes],
            account: accounts[0]
        });
        return msalResponse.accessToken;
    }

    const reloadUserFeeds = async () => {
        const result = await appService.getFeeds();
        if (result.success) {
            setUserFeeds(result.data);
            if (result.data!.length > 0) {
                setActiveUserFeed(result.data![0]);
            }
        } else {
            // problem loading data
        }
    }

    const handleEditFeed = async (userFeed: UserFeed): Promise<ServiceResult> => {
        // set state - add job to list
        const job: Job = {
            id: crypto.randomUUID(),
            name: name,
            status: 'In-Progress'
        };

        setJobs([...jobs, job]); // THIS CAUSES navigate() TO FAIL IN CHILD COMPONENT
        
        // API call that persists form submission to database
        const result = await appService.editFeed(userFeed);

        if (result.success) {
            // reload items from service
        }

        return result;
    }

    const router = createBrowserRouter([
        {
            path: '/',
            element: <RootLayout jobs={jobs}/>,
            children: [
                { path: '/home', element: <HomePage getAccessToken={getAccessToken} userFeeds={userFeeds} activeUserFeed={activeUserFeed}/> },
                {
                    path: '/feeds', element: <Outlet />, children: [
                        { path: '/feeds/manage', element: <ManageFeeds userFeeds={userFeeds}/> },
                        { path: '/feeds/edit', element: <EditFeed onSubmit={handleEditFeed} userFeeds={userFeeds}/> }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
    ]);

    useEffect(() => {
        reloadUserFeeds();
    }, []);

    return (
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    );
}

export default App;
```

**RootLayout.tsx (parent)**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Outlet, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { AppBar, Box, IconButton, Menu, MenuItem, ThemeProvider, Toolbar, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import SettingsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Settings';
import './RootLayout.css';
import { Job } from '../models';

type props = {
    jobs: Job[];
}

export default function RootLayout(props: props) {
    const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
    const [profileMenuAnchorElem, setProfileMenuAnchorElem] = useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
    
    const globalTheme = createTheme({
        palette: {
            primary: {
                main: '#0052cc',
            },
            secondary: {
                main: '#edf2ff',
            },
        }
    });

    const handleProfileMenuOpen = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        setProfileMenuAnchorElem(event.currentTarget);
    }

    const handleProfileMenuClose = () => {
        setProfileMenuAnchorElem(null);
    }

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={globalTheme}>
            <Box sx={{ height: 1, flexGrow: 1 }}>
                <AppBar position="static" sx={{}}>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <IconButton
                            size="large"
                            edge="start"
                            color="inherit"
                            aria-label="menu"
                            sx={{ mr: 2 }}
                        >
                            <MenuIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                        <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ pr: 4 }}>
                            <span id="header__title">DASHBOARD</span>
                        </Typography>
                        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <Link to={"/home"} className='router-nav-link'>Home</Link>
                            <Link to={"/feeds/manage"} className='router-nav-link'>Manage Feeds</Link>
                        </Box>
                        <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <Box>
                                <Typography>{accounts && accounts.length > 0 && accounts[0].username}</Typography>
                            </Box>
                            <IconButton
                                size="large"
                                aria-label="account of current user"
                                aria-controls="menu-appbar"
                                aria-haspopup="true"
                                onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}
                                color="inherit"
                            >
                                <SettingsIcon />
                            </IconButton>
                            <Menu
                                id="menu-appbar"
                                anchorEl={profileMenuAnchorElem}
                                anchorOrigin={{
                                    vertical: 'bottom',
                                    horizontal: 'right',
                                }}
                                keepMounted
                                transformOrigin={{
                                    vertical: 'top',
                                    horizontal: 'right',
                                }}
                                open={Boolean(profileMenuAnchorElem)}
                                onClose={handleProfileMenuClose}
                            >
                                <MenuItem onClick={handleProfileMenuClose}>My account</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem onClick={() => instance.logout()}>Logout</MenuItem>
                            </Menu>
                        </Box>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
                <Box sx={{ height: 'calc(100% - 64px)', overflowY: 'auto' }}>
                    <Outlet />
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}
```

**EditFeed.tsx (child)**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Box, Button, Stack, TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers-pro";
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { LoadingButton } from '@mui/lab';
import { UserFeed } from "../models";
import dayjs, { Dayjs } from "dayjs";
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';
dayjs.extend(utc);
import { ServiceResult } from "../services/AppService";

type props = {
    userFeeds: UserFeed[] | undefined;
    onSubmit: (userFeed: UserFeed) => Promise<ServiceResult>;
}

export default function EditFeed(props: props) {
    const location = useLocation();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [userFeed, setUserFeed] = useState<UserFeed>({ startDateTime: null, endDateTime: null });
    const [originalUserFeed, setOriginalUserFeed] = useState<UserFeed>();
    const [submitIsLoading, SetSubmitIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const handleNameChange = async (inUserFeed: UserFeed) => {
        setUserFeed(inUserFeed);
    }

    const handleSubmit = async () => {
        SetSubmitIsLoading(true);

        const result = await props.onSubmit(userFeed);

        if (result.success) {
            // redirect home
            navigate("/home");
        } else {
            // handle failure
        }

        SetSubmitIsLoading(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (location.state && location.state.userFeed && location.state.userFeed.userFeedId) {
            setUserFeed(location.state.userFeed);
            const userFeedCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(location.state.userFeed));
            setOriginalUserFeed(userFeedCopy);
        } else {
            setUserFeed({ ...userFeed });
            setOriginalUserFeed(undefined);
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <Box sx={{ height: 1, display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', boxSizing: 'border-box' }}>
            <Box sx={{ height: 0.5, display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>

                <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', width: 0.49, p: 2 }}>
                    <Typography variant="h5" sx={{ mb: 2 }}>{!originalUserFeed ? "Create" : "Edit"} Feed</Typography>
                    <TextField
                        label="Name"
                        id="filled-size-small"
                        value={userFeed?.feedName || ''}
                        onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                            handleNameChange({ ...userFeed, feedName: event.target.value });
                        }}
                    />

                    <TextField
                        label='Keywords'
                        id="filled-size-small"
                        value={userFeed?.requiredKeywords || ''}
                        onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                            setUserFeed({ ...userFeed, requiredKeywords: event.target.value });
                        }}
                    />
                    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', width: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                        <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', width: 0.49 }}>
                            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                                <DatePicker
                                    label="Start Date"
                                    timezone="UTC"
                                    value={dayjs.utc(userFeed?.startDateTime)}
                                    onChange={(newValue: Dayjs | null) => {
                                        setUserFeed({ ...userFeed, startDateTime: newValue ? newValue!.format('YYYY-MM-DD') : undefined });
                                    }}
                                />
                            </LocalizationProvider>
                        </Box>
                        <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', width: 0.49 }}>
                            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                                <DatePicker
                                    label="End Date"
                                    timezone="UTC"
                                    value={dayjs.utc(userFeed?.endDateTime)}
                                    onChange={(newValue: Dayjs | null) => {
                                        setUserFeed({ ...userFeed, endDateTime: newValue ? newValue!.format('YYYY-MM-DD') : undefined });
                                    }}
                                />
                            </LocalizationProvider>
                        </Box>
                    </Box>
                    <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
                        <LoadingButton
                            loading={submitIsLoading}
                            onClick={handleSubmit}
                            variant="contained">
                            Submit
                        </LoadingButton>
                        <Button href="/feeds/manage" variant="outlined">Cancel</Button>
                    </Stack>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    )
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "overwatch.react",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@arcgis/core": "^4.28.10",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.5.0",
    "@azure/msal-react": "^2.0.7",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.18",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.162",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.18",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.19.1",
    "@mui/x-data-grid-pro": "^6.19.3",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.19.0",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers-pro": "^6.19.3",
    "axios": "^1.6.5",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router": "^6.20.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.20.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash.debounce": "^4.0.9",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.15",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.10.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.4",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Please [edit] to include a ***complete*** and cohesive [mcve] so we can see how these code snippets relate to  and work with each other, e.g. the complete component code trying to effect the navigation action.

Comment: Drew, sorry for the lacking first draft.  I've rewritten the whole post and added more complete code examples.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that in your `App` component you are creating a new router each time `App` rerenders, like when the `jobs` or `userFeeds` state updates for example. This will obviously interrupt any active navigation actions.

Since you are not using the Data APIs you could simply use a regular router.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

function App(props: any) {
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
    
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState<Job[]>([]);
  const [userFeeds, setUserFeeds] = useState<UserFeed[]>();
  const [activeUserFeed, setActiveUserFeed] = useState<UserFeed>();

  const appService = useMemo(() => {
    return new AppService(instance, accounts[0], [props.msalConfig.scopes]);
  }, [instance, accounts, props.msalConfig.scopes]);

  const getAccessToken = async () => {
    const msalResponse = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({
      scopes: [props.msalConfig.scopes],
      account: accounts[0]
    });
    return msalResponse.accessToken;
  };

  const reloadUserFeeds = useCallback(async () => {
    const result = await appService.getFeeds();
    if (result.success) {
      setUserFeeds(result.data);
      if (result.data!.length > 0) {
        setActiveUserFeed(result.data![0]);
      }
    } else {
      // problem loading data
    }
  }, [appService, setUserFeeds, setActiveUserFeed]);

  const handleEditFeed = async (userFeed: UserFeed): Promise<ServiceResult> => {
    // set state - add job to list
    const job: Job = {
      id: crypto.randomUUID(),
      name,
      status: 'In-Progress'
    };

    setJobs([...jobs, job]);
    
    // API call that persists form submission to database
    const result = await appService.editFeed(userFeed);

    if (result.success) {
      // reload items from service
    }

    return result;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    reloadUserFeeds();
  }, []);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout jobs={jobs} />}>
          <Route
            path="home"
            element={(
              <HomePage
                getAccessToken={getAccessToken}
                userFeeds={userFeeds}
                activeUserFeed={activeUserFeed}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Route path="feeds">
            <Route path="manage" element={<ManageFeeds userFeeds={userFeeds} />} />
            <Route
              path="edit"
              element={(
                <EditFeed onSubmit={handleEditFeed} userFeeds={userFeeds} />
              )}
            />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

If you prefer to use the Data APIs, e.g. the Data router, then I suggest passing the states and callbacks down to routed components via a React context.

Example:

```
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

interface IAppContext {
  jobs: Job[];
  userFeeds: UserFeed[];
  activeUserFeed?: UserFeed;
  getAccessToken: () => Promise<string>;
  reloadUserFeeds: () => Promise<void>;
  handleEditFeed: (userFeed: UserFeed) => Promise<ServiceResult>;
}

export const AppContext = createContext<IAppContext>({
  jobs: [],
  userFeeds: [],
  activeUserFeed: undefined,
  getAccessToken: () => "",
  reloadUserFeeds: () => {},
  handleEditFeed: () => {},
});

export const useAppContext = () => useContext(AppContext);

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
    
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState<Job[]>([]);
  const [userFeeds, setUserFeeds] = useState<UserFeed[]>();
  const [activeUserFeed, setActiveUserFeed] = useState<UserFeed>();

  const appService = new AppService(instance, accounts[0], [props.msalConfig.scopes]);

  const getAccessToken = async () => {
    const msalResponse = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({
      scopes: [props.msalConfig.scopes],
      account: accounts[0]
    });
    return msalResponse.accessToken;
  }

  const reloadUserFeeds = async () => {
    const result = await appService.getFeeds();
    if (result.success) {
      setUserFeeds(result.data);
      if (result.data!.length > 0) {
        setActiveUserFeed(result.data![0]);
      }
    } else {
      // problem loading data
    }
  };

  const handleEditFeed = async (userFeed: UserFeed): Promise<ServiceResult> => {
    // set state - add job to list
    const job: Job = {
      id: crypto.randomUUID(),
      name,
      status: 'In-Progress'
    };

    setJobs(jobs => [...jobs, job]);
        
    // API call that persists form submission to database
    const result = await appService.editFeed(userFeed);

    if (result.success) {
      // reload items from service
    }

    return result;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    reloadUserFeeds();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        jobs,
        userFeeds,
        activeUserFeed,
        getAccessToken,
        reloadUserFeeds,
        handleEditFeed,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AppProvider;
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <RootLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: 'home', element: <HomePage /> },
      {
        path: 'feeds',
        children: [
          { path: 'manage', element: <ManageFeeds /> },
          { path: 'edit', element: <EditFeed /> }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
]);

function App(props: any) {
  return (
    <AppProvider>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </AppProvider>
  );
}
```

The `HomePage`, `ManageFeeds`, `EditFeed` components use the `useAppContext` hook to access the state and callback functions they were previously passed.

Example:

```
const { jobs } = useAppContext();
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.  I thought only a change in a functional component's props would trigger a rerender.  So I also thought that RootLayout would rerender when App.tsx calls setJobs, because jobs are passed to RootLayout via props.  But why would App.tsx also rerender when setJObs is called within it?  If that is the case then I have been misunderstanding what triggers a rerender for a long time.

Comment: @LNX React components rerender when (1) state or props update/change, and (2) when the parent component rerenders. I'm absolutely certain you've enqueued a state update in a React component and seen that this triggers *that* component to rerender. A trivial example is a simple component with a counter state and a button that increments it. 

Comment: I took your advice and opted to use the regular router instead of the Data API.  The navigate() call is working now.  Thanks for your help!